# JS - Compare individual numerical values:

Tags: javascript

I am evaluating if a condition is met between one numeric value and another, but I don't know how to add **individual values**.

**This example works for me:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alertone();
});

$(document).on('input','#enviara',alertone);

function alertone() {
  const total = Number($("#enviara").val().replace(".",""));

  if(total >= 52001 && total <= 52006) {
    $("#alerta-melilla,.layer-melilla").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#alerta-melilla,.layer-melilla").hide();
  };
};
```

But between the values **​​52001** & **52006**, I also want to check if the individual values ​​are written:

```
52009, 52012, 52019
```

I've tried these snippets, but it doesn't work for me:

```
if (total> = 52001 && total <= 52006 && 52009 && 52012 && 52019) { ...
```

---

```
if (total> = 52001 && total <= 52006 || 52009 || 52012 || 52019) { ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks @TopWebGhost

```
if (total >= 52001 && total <= 52006 || total === 52009 || total === 52012 || total === 52019)
```

:)

Comment: What you mean by "_I also want to check if the individual values ​​are written_"?

Comment: Didn't get your answer, may you explain your idea more?

as you mentioned :

" But between the values ​​52001 & 52006, I also want to check if the individual values ​​are written:

52009, 52012, 52019

"

how come 52009/12/19 are between 52001 and 52006??

Comment: For starters, you've got a typo: `total> =` should be `total >=`.

Comment: what do want to do if values is 52009, 52012, 52019.....?? Just apply nested if condition to check these values

Comment: It should be like this.
`if (total >= 52001 && total <= 52006 || total === 52009 || total === 52012 || total === 52019)`

Comment: @TopWebGhost Thanks! Bravo! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `Array` of the exceptional values you want to accept, and check if `total` is within that `Array`:

```
let validValues = [ 52009, 52012, 52019 ];
if ((total >= 52001 && total <= 52006) || validValues.contains(total)) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your other numbers in array and check if `total` exist in that array:

```
const total = 100;
let otherNumbers = [100, 200];

const otherNumbersMatches = otherNumbers.find(num => num === total);

if ((total >= 52001 && total <= 52006) || otherNumbersMatches) {
  // do something
  console.log('Matches')
}
```